# connect monitoring to ns1 record via terraform

Tags: dns, terraform

I have a terraform code that creating an ns1 record:

```
answers {
    answer = "MY_FIRST_IP"
    meta = {
      up = true
      georegion = "US-WEST,ASIAPAC"
    }
  }
  answers {
    answer = "MY_SECOUND_IP"
    meta = {
      up = true
      georegion = "EUROPE"
    }
```

and I want that in the second answer, it will depend if the monitoring I had is up, int the UI it looks like that:
[image]

and it works as expected, but when I try to create it in terraform with something like that:

```
answers {
    answer = "MY_FIRST_IP"
    meta = {
      up = true
      georegion = "US-WEST,ASIAPAC"
    }
  }
  answers {
    answer = "MY_SECOUND_IP"
    meta = {
      up = "My Monitoring Name"
      georegion = "EUROPE"
    }
```

i got this error:

```
Error: found error/s in answer metadata,found type mismatch for meta field 'Up'. expected [bool], got: string
```

I searched for it in the documentation, but I didn't found any mentions of this option

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work out for you:

- Create a datasource:

  ```
  resource "ns1_datasource" "example" {
   name       = "example"
   sourcetype = "nsone_monitoring"
  }
  ```
- Create a monitoring job:

  ```
  resource "ns1_monitoringjob" "uswest_monitor" {
   name          = "uswest"
   active        = true
   regions       = ["sjc", "sin", "lga"]
   job_type      = "tcp"
   frequency     = 60
   rapid_recheck = true
   policy        = "quorum"

   config = {
    ssl  = 1
    send = "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
    port = 443
    host = "example-elb-uswest.aws.amazon.com"
   }

   rules {
    value      = "200 OK"
    comparison = "contains"
    key        = "output"
   }
  }
  ```
- Create a datafeed:

  ```
  resource "ns1_datafeed" "uswest_feed" {
   name      = "uswest_feed"
   source_id = "${ns1_datasource.example.id}"

   config = {
    jobid = "${ns1_monitoringjob.uswest_monitor.id}"
   }
  }
  ```
- Then, you can create your record with the following answer pattern:

  ```
  answers {
   answer = "MY_SECOND_IP"
   meta    = {
    georegion = "EUROPE"
    up    = "{\"feed\":\"${ns1_datafeed.uswest_feed.id}\"}"
   }
  }
  ```